# how to capture image and crop it?

Tags: android

I want to capture an image and crop it, then with retrofit send this file to the server.
I try this code:
**intent open camera**

```
 Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "POST_IMAGE.jpg");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
    picUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA_IMAGE);
```

**onActivityResult**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_IMAGE) {
        path = data.getData();
        performCrop(path);
    }
}
```

**and the performCrop method**

```
private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
    try {
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", true);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 300);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 300);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

    }
}
```

but this code is wrong! how to do this?

if I save the captured image, then crop it from the gallery, it worked? how to do this?

*thank for your attention.*

Comment: Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`. There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) that you can use.

Comment: @CommonsWare crop method is right. I try with this method crop an image from the gallery and it worked.

Comment: There are 26,000+ Android device models. None have to support that undocumented `Intent` action. Even on those that *do* support it, since the `Intent` is undocumented, you may get results that your users do not like. Please **use an image-cropping library**.